# Chuck Norris entry in Expendables 2

Tags: plot-explanation, the-expendables-2

In Expendables 2... the scene where Chuck Norris enters. There are villains everywhere. They all suddenly get machine gunned down and a rocket takes out a tank. Since no character really cares to ask how the bullets and rockets came from everywhere, is this a part of the Chuck Norris joke as well?

Comment: So.....? What is the question?

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bullets and rockets didn't come from "everywhere".  If you watch the clip, Booker (aka Norris) is walking out from a cloud of smoke.  if you recall, there was a building just behind that smoke.  You can tell because the car he walks out from behind can be seen at 1:20 in the clip below.  So, it's very possible (probable) that he was on the roof of the building.  From that vantage point, he could have easily seen and hit every soldier and the tank.

Comment: looks like the video won't play outside of youtube. but thanks for that @Johnny Bones, somehow in my head... I remembered fire coming from everywhere. It seems to be coming from one direction only. So looks like that was not part of the Chuck Norris joke :)

Comment: In the bottom right corner, there is a youtube logo.  Just click on that and it will take you to youtube and the clip.  Sorry about that.